# Having problems when installing Label Studio with Anaconda

Tags: label-studio

I'm new to data field and I'm trying to install Label Studio using Anaconda following instructions on Label Studio official website:

```
conda create --name label-studio
conda activate label-studio
conda install psycopg2  # required for LS 1.7.2 only
pip install label-studio
```

However, when I entered "label-studio" to start using, I receive this:

```
WARNING: The scripts pyrsa-decrypt.exe, pyrsa-encrypt.exe, pyrsa-keygen.exe, pyrsa-priv2pub.exe, pyrsa-sign.exe and pyrsa-verify.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\ThinkPad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script normalizer.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\ThinkPad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script tqdm.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\ThinkPad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script jsonschema.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\ThinkPad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script django-admin.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\ThinkPad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts rq.exe, rqinfo.exe and rqworker.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\ThinkPad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script nltk.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\ThinkPad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script label-studio-converter.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\ThinkPad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script label-studio.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\ThinkPad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed Django-3.2.25 asgiref-3.7.2 attrs-23.2.0 azure-core-1.30.1 azure-storage-blob-12.19.1 bleach-5.0.1 boto3-1.34.57 botocore-1.34.57 cachetools-5.3.3 certifi-2024.2.2 cffi-1.16.0 charset-normalizer-3.3.2 click-8.1.7 colorama-0.4.6 cryptography-42.0.5 defusedxml-0.7.1 django-annoying-0.10.6 django-cors-headers-3.6.0 django-csp-3.7 django-debug-toolbar-3.2.1 django-environ-0.10.0 django-extensions-3.1.0 django-filter-2.4.0 django-model-utils-4.1.1 django-rq-2.5.1 django-storages-1.12.3 django-user-agents-0.4.0 djangorestframework-3.13.1 drf-generators-0.3.0 google-api-core-2.17.1 google-auth-2.28.1 google-cloud-core-2.4.1 google-cloud-storage-2.15.0 google-crc32c-1.5.0 google-resumable-media-2.7.0 googleapis-common-protos-1.62.0 humansignal-drf-yasg-1.21.9 idna-3.6 inflection-0.5.1 isodate-0.6.1 jmespath-1.0.1 joblib-1.3.2 jsonschema-3.2.0 label-studio-1.11.0 label-studio-converter-0.0.57 label-studio-tools-0.0.3 launchdarkly-server-sdk-7.5.0 lxml-5.1.0 nltk-3.6.7 pandas-2.2.1 pyasn1-modules-0.3.0 pydantic-1.10.14 python-dateutil-2.9.0.post0 requests-2.31.0 rq-1.10.1 rsa-4.9 s3transfer-0.10.0 sentry-sdk-1.40.6 tqdm-4.66.2
(label-studio) PS C:\Users\ThinkPad>
(label-studio) PS C:\Users\ThinkPad> lable-studio
lable-studio : The term 'lable-studio' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ lable-studio
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (lable-studio:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I'm using Window 10 and I have Python 3.12.
Can you please tell the problems and how to solve them? Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have Python path added to your environment variables.
Try adding `C:\Users\ThinkPad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts` to PATH.
Here's how to do it: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/adding-python-path-to-windows-10-or-11-path-environment-variable/

Comment: I read the article and I'm pretty sure that Python path was added but I still have the same problem.